# had a baby / had a boy / had a son

Tags: phrase-usage

I have the following sentence in my book:

> Ann **had a baby** yesterday. He was born ...

Is it possible to say:

> Ann **had a son** yesterday. He was born ...
>
> Ann **had a boy** yesterday. He was born ...

I heard somewhere that baby is preferrable to say for newborns. Is it right? So, is it possible to say "had a son", "had a boy" in the same context?

By the way, is it idiomatic for fathers to say similar? If not, please write idiomatic versions.

> I **had a baby** yesterday. He was born ...
>
> I **had a son** yesterday. He was born ...
>
> I **had a boy** yesterday. He was born ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use "had a son" in the context in which you had already established that Ann has given birth:

> Ann's baby has arrived, she had a boy!

Otherwise, there's no context to suggest that you are using the idiomatic "have" meaning give birth.

For fathers, it would be better to say, for example, "My wife has had a baby". The father hasn't actually given birth!  There are other ways to express this: "I've become a father (for the second time)"